# Python class bug

Tags: python, class

My remove and new quantity methods dont work and I have no idea why. Here is my code:

```
# Type code for classes here
class ItemToPurchase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.item_description = 'none'
        self.item_name = 'none'
        self.item_price= 0
        self.item_quantity = 0

    def print_item_description(self):
        print(f'{self.item_name}: {self.item_description}')

class ShoppingCart():
    def __init__(self, customer_name='none', current_date='January 1, 2016'):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.current_date = current_date
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, item ):
        ''' Adds an item to cart_items list. Has parameter of type ItemToPurchase. Does not return anything. '''
        self.items.append(item)

    def remove_item(self, item ):
        ''' Removes item from cart_items list. Has a string (an item's name) parameter. Does not return anything.
            If item name cannot be found, output this message: Item not found in cart. Nothing removed. '''
        delete = False
        for item in self.items:
            if self.items == item:
                to_be_deleted = self.items[item]
                delete = True
            else:
                print("Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.")
        if delete == True:
            del self.items[to_be_deleted]


    def modify_item(self, item, new_quantity):
        '''Modifies an item's quantity. Has a parameter of type ItemToPurchase. Does not return anything.
            If item can be found (by name) in cart, modify item in cart.'''

        if item in self.items:
            item.quantity = new_quantity
        else:
            print("Item not found in cart. Nothing modified.")

    def get_num_items_in_cart(self):
        '''Returns quantity of all items in cart. Has no parameters.'''
        num_items = 0
        for item in self.items:

            num_items += item.item_quantity
        #return the num_Items
        return num_items

    def get_cost_of_cart(self):
        '''Determines and returns the total cost of items in cart. Has no parameters.'''

        return sum(item.item_price * item.item_quantity for item in self.items)

    def print_total(self):

        '''Outputs total of objets in cart.
        If cart is empty, outputs this message: CART IS EMPTY.'''

        print(f"{self.customer_name}'s Shopping Cart - {self.current_date}")
        number_items = self.get_num_items_in_cart()
        print(f'Number of Items: {number_items}\n')
        total_cost = self.get_cost_of_cart()
        if total_cost == 0:
            print("SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY\n")
            print(f'Total: ${total_cost}')
            return False
        else:
            for item in self.items:
                item_cost = item.item_quantity * item.item_price

                print(f'{item.item_name} {item.item_quantity} @ ${item.item_price} = ${item_cost}')
            print()
            total_cost = self.get_cost_of_cart()
            print(f'Total: ${total_cost}')

    def print_descriptions(self):
        ''' Outputs each item's description'''
        print(f"{self.customer_name}'s Shopping Cart - {self.current_date}\n")
        for item in self.items:
            print("Item Descriptions")
            print(f'{item.item.name}: {item.item_description}')

def print_menu():
    print("MENU\na - Add item to cart\nr - Remove item from cart\nc - Change item quantity\ni - Output items' descriptions\no - Output shopping cart\nq - Quit\n")


def execute_menu(choice , shopping_cart):
    if choice == "o":
        print("OUTPUT SHOPPING CART")

        shopping_cart.print_total()


    elif choice == "i":
        print("OUTPUT ITEMS' CART")
        shopping_cart.print_descriptions()


    elif choice == "a":
        print("ADD ITEM TO CART\nEnter the item name:")
        item_name = input()
        print("Enter the item description:")
        item_description = input()
        print("Enter the item price:")
        item_price = int(input())
        print("Enter the item quantity:")
        item_quantity = int(input())
        New_item = ItemToPurchase()
        New_item.item_name = item_name
        New_item.item_price = item_price
        New_item.item_quantity = item_quantity
        New_item.item_description = item_description
        shopping_cart.add_item(New_item)


    elif choice =="r":
        print("REMOVE ITEM FROM CART\nEnter name of item to remove:")
        removed_item = input()
        shopping_cart.remove_item(removed_item)

    elif choice == "i":
        '''Implement Change item quantity menu option in execute_menu(). Hint: Make new ItemToPurchase object before using ModifyItem() method. '''

        print("CHANGE ITEM QUANTITY\nEnter the item name:")
        Item = ItemToPurchase()
        Item.item_name = input()
        print("Enter the new quantity:")
        Item.item_quantity = input()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    shopping_cart = ShoppingCart()
    print("Enter customer's name:")
    shopping_cart.customer_name = input()

    print("Enter today's date:")
    shopping_cart.current_date = input()
    print()
    print(f"Customer name: {shopping_cart.customer_name}\nToday's date: {shopping_cart.current_date}")
    print()


    print_menu()
    print("Choose an option:")
    while True:
        choice = input()

        if choice in "arcioq":
            if choice == 'q':
                break

            else:
                execute_menu(choice, shopping_cart)
                print()
                print_menu()

        print("Choose an option:")
```

I think with remove I'm comparing wrong data types and i cant seem to make it work. By the way, the  function names cannot change and i cannot add any new functions. I can only use doc strings of preexisting methods and classes and functions

Comment: "methods don't work" isn't a very clear problem description. Please say a bit more. Also -- please give a [mcve] with an emphasis on "minimal".

Comment: Well, "c" isn't in your `execute_menu` choices.  There are two "i" choices.  One is wrong .  These types of problems are best solved with a careful look at the code or simply stepping through a source debugger looking for logic errors.

Comment: Ive been trying to debug for such a long time. I think the def remove and def modify_item function definitions are wrong but after 1 hour of rewriting and debugging I can confidently say I have no clue why.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `del` correctly.  I think you've confused `del` with the `.remove()` method of a list.

`del self.items[to_be_deleted]` makes no sense.  `self.items` is a list, and list indexes must be integers.  But `to_be_deleted` is not an integer; it is an actual item in the list.

If you want to use `del`, you need the integer index of the list item to be removed.

But since you have the actual object itself, you can call `self.items.remove()` instead, which takes the actual object as an argument.

Comment: As John Gordon suggested, I rewrote the last 2 lines of the def remove_item() function to be remove with 

if delete == True:
            self.items.remove(to_be_deleted)
I think its still wrong tho

Comment: @Coolmathgames The `for item` loop shadows the `item` parameter.  The name needs to be different.  Then you need to compare `<newname>.item_name` to the parameter `item`.  This isn't really a suitable question for SO.  You need a tutor to guide you through the debug process.

Comment: Would this work?
delete = False
        for i in self.items:
            if self.items == item:
                to_be_deleted = self.items[i]
                delete = True
            else:
                print("Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.")
        if delete == True:
            self.items.remove(to_be_deleted)

Comment: @Coolmathgames No, and code in comments is hard to read.  That's why this question isn't a good format for SO.  `i` is the item.  `i.item_name == item` is what to check.